# Today is in list of dates

Tags: views, theming

Trying to check if variable 'today' is in a list of dates in Views Conditional Field. Both values print out nicely.

Today (var php):
24/06/2019

List of dates (var field_dates):
24/06/2019, 25/06/2019, 26/06/2019

However; when I to this, it returns false? How come?

```
{% if php in field_dates %}
  True
{% else %}
  False
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I doubt that `field_dates` simply contains all dates. They are probably nested somewhere in `field_dates.values` or similar. Please install the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) sub-module Kint and then in your template do `{{ kint(field_dates) }}` to get a pretty-printed `var_dump` and find out what you have in there. Or just `{{ kint() }}`.

Comment: It does contain them :) If you just print the values, it they show up as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to use the [`striptags`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html) filter. This works like a charm!

```
{% if php|striptags in field_dates|striptags %}
  True
{% else %}
  False
{% endif %}
```